# Creating Shelley Wallet Sync takes way too much time

Tags: wallet

Here is how I create a wallet:

```
  let recoveryPhrase = Seed.generateRecoveryPhrase();
  console.log(recoveryPhrase);

  let mnemonic_sentence = Seed.toMnemonicList(recoveryPhrase);
  //console.log(mnemonic_sentence);

  let passphrase = "pass";
  let name = "name";

  let wallet = await walletServer.createOrRestoreShelleyWallet(
    name,
    mnemonic_sentence,
    passphrase,
    null,
    10
  );
```

It does create a wallet, however, I'm also waiting for the wallet to get synced and while it gets syncing I cannot retrieve balance information.

Listing wallets in cli via `cardano-wallet wallets list` command:

```
"name": "name",
    "id": "wallet-id",
    "tip": {
        "height": {
            "quantity": 6015225,
            "unit": "block"
        },
        "epoch_number": 279,
        "time": "2021-07-23T02:30:50Z",
        "absolute_slot_number": 35441159,
        "slot_number": 276359
    },
    "passphrase": {
        "last_updated_at": "2022-09-09T07:58:21.052641502Z"
    },
    "address_pool_gap": 10,
    "state": {
        "status": "syncing",
        "progress": {
            "quantity": 77.19,
            "unit": "percent"
        }
    },
    "delegation": {
        "next": [],
        "active": {
            "status": "not_delegating"
        }
    },
    "assets": {
        "total": [],
        "available": []
    }
}
```

Why do Cardano Wallets need to be synced? Is there anything that I can do to speed up the syncing process?

Answer (score 1):

> Why do Cardano Wallets need to be synced?

An unsynced wallet will be empty. It is only by reading the chain that transactions to and from the wallet can be found and the balance adjusted accordingly.

You did not say *how* long its taking. Is it an hour, 10 hours, 3 days? What is your expectation?